# OBJC: incompatible types in initialization

Tags: objective-c

Hey gusys, why im getting this error?

The code is this. Im receiving a string on my function (a string like this "1799.00");

```
-(void) priceFormat:(NSString*)preco {

float x = preco; /* Incompatible types in initialization */

   if(x > 0) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float x = [preco floatValue];
```

You have to convert the string to a floating-point value.